# list variables to individual data.frames

Tags: r, list, do.call

Let's say I have a `list` of 30 `data.frames`, each containing 2 variables (called **value**, and **rank**), called `myList`

I'd know I can use

```
my.DF <- do.call("cbind", myList)
```

to create the output `my.DF` containing all the variables next to each other.

It is possible to `cbind` each variable individually into it's own `data.frame` i.e to just have a new `data.frame` of just the 2nd variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can extract the second column by looping over the `list` (`lapply`) and wrap with `data.frame`.

```
data.frame(lapply(myList, `[`, 2))
```

If we want to separate the variables,

```
lapply(names(myList[[1]]), function(x) 
          do.call(cbind,lapply(myList, `[`, x)))
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
myList <- list( data.frame(value=1:6, rank= sample(6)), 
                data.frame(value=7:12, rank=sample(6)))
```